# Makeindex - Styling the \printindex?

Tags: formatting, indexing, naming

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to change the titel of the printindex command? It is "Index" by default.
2. How can I format the index as a multi column, alphabetic sorted list?

[image: printindex title]
[image: Alphabetically sorted printindex]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the answers depend on what document class you're using.  however,

1. both the basic latex classes (book et al.) and and ams-latex classes (amsbook et al.) provide the command `\indexname` with a default value "Index".  so

   ```
   \renewcommand{\indexname}{New name}
   ```

   will change the title.  (the `babel` package does this already for a number of languages.)
2. both `book.cls` and `amsbook.cls` provide a two-column index style.  if you're creating your own class, you might consider "borrowing" the code from one of those classes.  documented code is given in the `.dtx` files `classes` for basic latex and `amsclass` for the ams-latex classes.  "human readable" versions of the documented code are given in `.pdf` files of the same names as the `.dtx` files.  all are on ctan, and they are probably also on your tex installation; try typing `texdoc classes` or `texdoc amsclass` at the command line.

to get the content sorted, you need to use `makeindex`; that is well documented in several places, including lamport's latex manual and the "companionn", as well as with `texdoc makeindex`.  be sure to pay attention to the use of the "sort field" for math entries, entries with accented letters, and other special cases that may cause entries to diverge from the expected alphabetical order.

**addendum:** the `imakeidx` package is a good choice if more than one index
is being produced.  it isn't necessary to identify an entry for the main index by anything other than the basic `\index` command; for an odditional index, the
designation of that index is entered as an option: `\index[<name>]{<entry>}`.  a
further advantage of `imakeidx` is that in most cases, a second compilation pass
isn't needed.  there are some caveats; for details, see the package documentation.

Answer (score 15):

1. Redefine `\indexname`. For example:

   ```
   \renewcommand\indexname{The Index}
   ```
2. There are [`imakeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) and [`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) packages to change the style of the index. Columns and headings, and other settings.
3. You can specify a `.ist` file when using [`makeindex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) program to change the output of `makeindex`. See the document of `makeindex`.

---

A sample `.ist` file:

```
% sample.ist
% Usage
%     makeindex -s sample.ist foo.aux
preamble "
\\begin{theindex}
  \\providecommand*\\indexgroup[1]{\\indexspace
    \\item \\textbf{#1}\\nopagebreak}
"

postamble "\n\n\\end{theindex}\n"

group_skip "  %\n  \\indexspace\n  %\n"

headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "  %\n  \\indexgroup{"
heading_suffix "}\n  %\n"

numhead_positive "Numbers";
numhead_negative "Numbers";
symhead_positive "Symbols";
symhead_negative "Symbols";
```

Answer (score 14):

I'm just expanding Leo Liu's item #2 a little. `imakeidx` can easily help you on setting a custom index title and column numbers through (from documentation):

- `title`: is the title that is typeset at the beginning of the specific index; if not
  specified, the `\indexname` value is used.
- `columns`: accepts an integer representing the number of columns in the index;
  this is silently ignored if the `original` or the `twocolumn` options are
  set; the number can even be 1.

A quick addition to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=My custom index title,columns=2]
```

will do the job. If you have, say, a custom `mystyle.ist` style, you can also use the `options` option as well:

- `options`: is the list of options to be passed to the sorting and formatting program; this list is a balanced text of program options, separated with the syntax required by the sorting and formatting program. For example, in order to use a different `makeindex` sorting and formatting style `mystyle.ist` and avoiding any message in the screen output write `options=-s mystyle`.

Regarding a custom `makeidx` style, unfortunately I have no experience with it. I strongly recommend chapter 11 from "The LaTeX Companion" book, called *Index Generation*. `:)`

Answer (score 8):

1. Redefine `\indexname` like this : `\renewcommand{\indexname}{My index}`.
2. You define a .ist file that stores your preferences for the style of the index. For the example you want (alphabetic list starting by the letters and dots before page numbers), you add the following lines to your .ist file :

> ```
> >     heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
> >     heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n" 
> >     headings_flag 1
> ```

and also

```
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
```

If it based on a book derived class, the index will be on two columns anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work well with LuaLatex. It provides the dots, but no the bold big letters. Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am using amsmidx. I had to use

```
\backmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Author Index}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Author Index}
\printindex{author}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Subject Index}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Subject Index}
\printindex{subject}
```

Don't add the index name to `\printindex` or you will get two indexes with each name, use `\renewcommand{\indexname}{My Index Name}` instead. Thanks to two commenters below, but adding a `\clearpage` just before the second `\addcontentsline` made my table of contents disappear.

Comment: With what package for multiple indices?

Comment: The `\clearpage` after `\backmatter` is superfluous because `\backmatter` will issue `\clearpage` resp. `\cleardoublepage` (depending on the state of `@openright`). On the other hand, a `\clearpage` before the second `\addcontentsline` is missing, and this will cause a wrong page number entry in the ToC.

Comment: `amsmidx` is meant to be used with `amsbook`, and is presumed to be incompatible with any non-ams document class.  when used with `amsbook`, the proper access is `\Printindex{author}{Author Index} \Printindex{subject}{Subject Index}` (note the uppercase `\Printindex`); the toc entries are added automatically.  `amsmidx` was created long before `imakeidx`; now that `imakeidx` exists, it's a *much* better choice.